# How can I set a placeholder variable in page.tpl.php from a page callback?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a value in page.tpl.php that I would like to set in page callbacks, independently from the main content.

In page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $placeholder ?>

<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

What I would like to do in the page callback:

```
function my_module_page_callback_foo() {
  $placeholder = 'foo';
  return 'Page Content';
}
```

Obviously, that isn't going to get me very far.

I'm hesitant to use hook_preprocess_page because then I'll have unnecessary conditional logic to determine what the menu item is (won't I?). Is there another, 'drupal way' of doing this?

I'm coming from a more 'Zend-y' world where I have access to my view and my layout variables from the controller.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities, not sure which one would work best for you. There isn't a really easy way to do that.

I would say the "drupal way" of doing that would be to expose your additional content as a block. You can configure that to only show up on specific pages and place it above the main content.

There is also [hook_page_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7), but that requires the same conditonal checks as a template_preprocess.

You could also return a [render array](http://drupal.org/node/930760) in your page callback and then display it separately in your page.tpl.php, something like `render($page['content']['system_main']['part_a'])` and so on. You could do that only in a [template suggestion](http://drupal.org/node/223440) for a specific page, like page--yourpath.tpl.php.

To avoid messing with page.tpl.php too much, there is also the possibility of overriding the so called '[delivery_callback](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_page/7)' (see [menu_execute_active_handler()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_execute_active_handler/7) in your menu router item for that page. The default delivery callback is [drupal_deliver_html_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7).

Comment: Hmm. You give me multiple choices. How do I select the part of your answer that I actually found useful?

Comment: By the by, the part I found useful was the render array. I would like to select that as my answer.

Comment: You can only accept/vote the full answer, but you can state in a comment (what you already did ;)) which suggestion you actually liked/implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're adding this directly into your page.tpl.php it seems like this should stay part of your theme and not deviate in origin. Not that I actually advocate adding things directly into the page template at all. Why not just create a region and place what you need into a programmatic block?

Anyhow, here is a theme only approach...

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  $vars['placeholder'] = MYTHEME_build_placeholder();
}

function MYTHEME_build_placeholder() {
  $output = 'Hello!'
  return $output;
}
```